# C# export mysql database to excel file

Tags: c#

Hi i created a pos software but i needed a function to export data to excel so i created a class to export and i get and error when i try to export the file so here is some of my code that i worked on.

```
public void PrefrlivoExcel()
{
    MySqlConnection connection = Connection.prevzemiKonekcija();

    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    string sqlSelectAll = "SELECT * from prodavnica.artikli";
    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, connection);

    adapter.Fill(tabela);
    tabelaSmetka(tabela);
}
void tabelaSmetka(DataTable tabela)
{
    object missValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    app.Visible = false;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

    for (int i = 0; i < tabela.Columns.Count; i++)
    {

        ws.Cells[1, i + 1] = tabela.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tabela.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < tabela.Columns.Count; j++)
        {

            ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = tabela.Rows[i][j].ToString();
        }


    }
    ws.Name = tabela.TableName;
    wb.SaveAs(@"D:\artikli.xlsx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, missValue, missValue, missValue, missValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, missValue, missValue, missValue, missValue);
    wb.Close(true, missValue, missValue);
    MessageBox.Show("Податоците беа успешно префрлени во Excel !");
}
```

The error is as below:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: dataTable'

adapter was null.

Comment: If you stepped through the debugger, I'd assume you'd not see a variable adapter before it's used. As you are instantiating a variable named adapter1

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: did u initialized tabela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not initialized your `DataTable` variable. In this case, `tablea`. Initialize the `DataTable` before passing it into `DataAdapter`.

```
DataTable tablea = new DataTable();

DataTable dt = null;

SqlConnection con = new 
SqlConnection(@"server=sampleserver;database=Fiddle;uid=sa;pwd=sa");
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
string sql = "select * from employee";
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Thank you i did not saw that.. Best regards Kurafte